# Is there a way to get SNAFU's `.backtrace()` on arbitrary `&dyn std::error::Error` trait objects?

Tags: error-handling, rust, dynamic-dispatch

[RFC 2504](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2504-fix-error.md) will add a required `fn backtrace(&self) -> Option<&Backtrace>` to all `std::error::Error`. This is not ready yet, so for now, [SNAFU](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.5.0/snafu/index.html), an error helper macro, polyfills this by tying an [`ErrorCompat`](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.5.0/snafu/trait.ErrorCompat.html) trait to all types generated by the macro. This allows for backtrace support before it lands in Rust nightly.

However, this `ErrorCompat` trait is not implemented for all implementors of `std::error::Error`. I want to — in some generic error printing code — be able to display the chain of causes along with the stacktrace associated with where the SNAFU error was instantiated. Unfortunately, the [`source()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.source) function returns `&(dyn Error + 'static)`.

```rust
use std::error::Error as StdError;
use snafu::{ResultExt, ErrorCompat};

fn main() {
    let err: Result<(), _> = Err(std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, "oh no!"));

    let err = err.with_context(|| parse_error::ReadInput {
        filename: "hello"
    });

    let err = err.with_context(|| compile_error::ParseStage);

    // some generic error handling code
    if let Err(err) = err {
        // `cause` is type &(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)
        let cause = err.source().unwrap();

        if let Some(err) = /* attempt to downcast cause into &dyn snafu::ErrorCompat trait object */ {
            println!("{}", err.backtrace().unwrap());
        }
    }
}

pub mod compile_error {
    use snafu::{Snafu, Backtrace};
    #[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
    #[snafu(visibility(pub(super)))]
    pub enum Error {
        #[snafu(display("Error parsing code: {}", source))]
        ParseStage {
           source: crate::parse_error::Error,
           backtrace: Backtrace
        },
    }
}

pub mod parse_error {
    use snafu::{Snafu, Backtrace};
    #[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
    #[snafu(visibility(pub(super)))]
    pub enum Error {
        #[snafu(display("Could not read input {:?}: {}", filename, source))]
        ReadInput {
           filename: std::path::PathBuf,
           source: std::io::Error,
           backtrace: Backtrace
        },
    }
}
```

I've looked at `std::any::Any::downcast_ref` but this is for downcasting to a struct, not downcasting a trait object to another trait object. I'd like to avoid having to list out all possible concrete-typed SNAFU errors in my error-handling code.

I could cryo-freeze myself until RFC 2504 is (fully) implemented but surely there's some way to do this.

Comment: Cryo-freezing seems to be the best option for now.

Answer (score 1):

A `dyn Error` has the methods of `Error` and nothing else. If the backtrace cannot be deduced from those methods then where else could that information come from?

Unfortunately [RFC 2504](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2504-fix-error.md) is not yet stabilised, so you will need to be cryogenically frozen until at least Rust 1.39 if you want to wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I missed this because nightly `std` docs weren't recompiled, but [`#![feature(backtrace)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.backtrace) is in nightly right now. SNAFU still needs to add support for it, so I'm still stuck on getting this all working.